# Viewing Node.js code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm new to web development. I'm writing an application with Node.js and want to use MySQL. I'm not sure how web technology works, but would people visiting my site be able to see my database credentials? According to the MySQL documentation (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) this is how to connect to a MySQL database.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: Yes, if they can access your file system. No regular user will know how to hack into your system to achieve that though. If they have access to the FS, then you are in bad shape. If you're mysqld is listening to the world on port 3306, then you should rethink that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
Another noob question: I'm guessing that port 3306 reserved for mysqldb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they won't be able to see your code unless you run this on the client, which you shouldn't be able to or should, at all.

The example above runs on the backend and the query and data get displayed in the console, so it will only be accessible from the server and no clients connecting to it should be able see it, also you are not using anything to display a website ( based on the example above ) so you should not worry about it. If you want to, check out [express](http://expressjs.com/) or the [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) library for node.js.

After a while you should get the hang of it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

People won't see your database credentials unless you publish the file in plain .js rather than executing it in node.js.

However, as an extra security measure, please prevent your database from connections outside the server, such as setting up a firewall to prevent port 3306 from outside connections, and use only 'localhost' users in your mysql database.